# Can't reach docker container from the internet when using host network

Tags: docker, networking, debian, firewall, iptables

I tried to set up different containers using the --network host setting and could not connect to any of them. The debian and docker installations are as unmodified as it gets.

Using the bridge network option works, but I want to use the host network because of performance reasons (mainly for running gameservers). I can also reach them from the host via curl but not through the internet.

Could this be a problem with iptables or am I missing some kind of configuration to allow containers to be accessible from outside?

Some system information:

- Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5
- docker-compose version 1.21.0
- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- iptables -S output: https://pastebin.com/nwNXKn4p
- Netstat for the port one of the containers is using:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :27015
    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27015           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8671/./srcds_linux  
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27015           0.0.0.0:*                           8671/./srcds_linux
```

Comment: Did you add the container's port to UFW? I don't see it in the iptables output. Also I'm assuming the port for the container is 27015 since you didn't show the parameters for `docker run` or the `docker-compose` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem. I whitelisted the ports with sudo ufw allow 27015/tcp and it worked!